# New Order and Notify Customer by Email is Not Working in Magento

Tags: email, magento-1.9

Now I am currently working on vendors based site, Its running on Magento 1.9.2.2 version.

After I placed the order, admin and vendors got mail, But the customer did not get the mail.

Also in the order edit page (Admin-panel -> Sales -> Order -> Edit)  added some comments and checked "Notify Customer by Email" then i submitted, 
But Customer didnot receive any mail regarding this.

In the back end I changed the order to invoice, shipping and credit-memo that time only customer got mail.
and also Notify Customer by Email is working fine.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Make sure corn job is set or not. Magento use cron for send email to customer. Please check http://magentosolution.com/index.php/2015/04/29/magento-ce-1-9-1-not-using-for-sending-emails/ for more details.